# Redirect the Page after Form is Submitted - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

**Q1**. How could I place a code that can redirect the page after the form submitted??

**Q2**. I am looking some article about `return value`, anyone please recommend some good article for me.

```
    <form method="post" name="formName">
    <input type="text" value="Name" name="cName">
        <br>
    <input type="submit" onClick="return fValidator(this)">
    </form>


<script language="javascript1.8.5" type="text/javascript">

function fValidator(){
    var vName = document.formName.cName;
    var nameReg = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if (vName.value != ''){
        if (vName.value.match(nameReg)){
            alert("Your form is sumitted now!");
            return true;
            location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");

        }   else{
                alert("Alphabet only!");
                return false;
            }
    }   else{
            alert("Fill the mandatory field!");
            return false;
        }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want submit the form and then redirect it to some URL??

Comment: do you want to submit your form to the php script it self, or do you missed the action  ? because i'm not seeing any treatment for your posted data

Comment: What do you need about return value;?

Comment: I want the submit the form and then redirect to new page.
I am new to learning Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "onsubmit".

Eg: `<form onsubmit="myFunction()">`

This lets you to control the page behaviour after submitting the form.

Comment: I am asking How to redirect to other page after submitted the form.

Comment: "This lets you control the page behavior after submitting the form" suggests that you can either make an alert box alerting the user that form was received or you can use javascript redirection methods to redirect the user.

I suggest you to study up properties like window.location.href, window.open() etc.

Comment: Appreciated advised. I have no idea which part i need to study.

Comment: Modify line 1 according to my answer. Also, if you find my answer helpful, mark it as an answer.